# Any way to receive LinkedIn emails at an alternative address?

Tags: email, notifications, linkedin

LinkedIn requires you to set a "primary" email address, which will be visible to the others. However, they also send tons of emails to this address.

With some services such as Github, you're able to have one email address shown publicly while receiving notifications at another email address.

Is there anything similar for LinkedIn?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible by default to switch emails, but LinkedIn can do so if they "detect any issues" with your primary email address.

> [image]
>
> **[https://www.linkedin.com/help/](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/59/benefits-of-adding-a-secondary-email-address-to-your-linkedin-account?lang=en)**

Answer (score 0):

My email address is not visible to others.  Maybe you should create a business page.  It can have a separate email address.

> Why Create a LinkedIn Business Page?
>
> You may think that a business page is one more thing to do. You're barely hanging on as it is. And as a small business owner, you are your business, and your business is you. So why do you need another page to manage?
>
> The good news is. You don't have to manage it if you don't want to. You can set it and forget about it. Or you can start posting and engaging as a company. That's up to you. And the benefits far outweigh the time.
>
> A LinkedIn business page:
>
> • establishes credibility. After all, you're building a company, not a pop-up shop
>
> • helps potential customers find you. LinkedIn is not only a social site; it's also a robust database
>
> • automatically adds a page link and logo to your personal profile in the Experience section
>
> • gives you access to data, such as engagement rates, click rates, and more on your business posts

From [How to create a business page](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/how-create-business-page-jeri-aanonson/)